# import openjdk11 in eclipse, aspectj report error

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

i import openjdk11 instead of jdk8. the aspectj always report error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.ClassPathManager$JImageEntry.<init>(ClassPathManager.java:332)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.ClassPathManager.addPath(ClassPathManager.java:110)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.ClassPathManager.<init>(ClassPathManager.java:84)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.<init>(BcelWorld.java:285)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:841)
a ... lipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

Compile error: IllegalStateException thrown: Unexpectedly unable to initialize a JRT filesystem
```

i am sure it works when using JDK8.

Comment: You'd have to dive deeper, but I'd not be surprised if the underlying problem is related to aspectJ not being able to instrument classes in the Java11 class file format.

Comment: i change to openjdk9, it also report this error.